# reset window function when the time gap is over one hour

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have a dataset already sorted by a window function in sql:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOAN_NUMBER, CAST(CREATED_DATE AS DATE) ORDER BY LOAN_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE) AS ROW_IDX
```

shown as above. I wonder if there's a way that reset the ROW_IDX when the CREATED_DATE has begun to have a value with over one hour gap to the minimum datetime in a specific day.

For example, the row index for row 3 should be 1 because the time gap between 2016-11-03 15:39:16.000 and 2016-11-03 12:44:11.000 is over one hour.And row index of row 4 will be 2.

I've tried several ways to manipulate the datatime column, since the consideration is about 'gap' instead of moments of the day, no rounding methods worked perfectly.

Comment: So, just two groups per day? one starting from the min datetime and one that exceeded the *hour gap to the minimum datetime*?

Comment: yeah, the grouping is based on account, created_date(now as date). The problem is that if the same account reappears over one hour later then it should be recounted, and always within one hour count once. I am thinking of some window way and didn't make it.

Comment: I see. One set with accounts with min datetime, the other with the rest. But what if in the rest, there are again hour gaps from the new min datetime?

Comment: Should the hour gap start from min datetime of each group or last datetime? Should difference between `2016-11-03 12:51:43.000` and `2016-11-03 15:39:16.000` be considered for grouping? last datetime one is easy. the min version is recursive.

Comment: the hour gap for an account in a particular day begins from the min datetime for that account in that day. when we move to row 3, it's as if 2016-11-03 15:39:16.000 becomes the new min datetime, and row 4 will be compared with it

Comment: What about row 5 on the same day after row 4? What will it be compared with? Row 3 or row 4?

Answer (score 0):

Are mean ,when the gap more than 60 minutes, will restart at 1?
Which version are you use? If it is SQL Server 2012+, you can try this.

The following query is not satisfying, but wish can give you help.

1. Calculating the diff minutes between continuous two line.
2. Check the diff minutes whether greater than one hour
3. Get row number base on the gap time has same situation continuously.

Sorry if I can not describe clear. My english is not well.

```
    ;WITH tb(RptDate,ISSUE_ID,ACCOUNT,CREATED_DATE )AS(
        select '2017-01-17','35775','76505156','2016-11-03 12:44:11.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 12:51:43.000' UNION
      --  select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 13:47:43.000' UNION
      --  select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 14:45:43.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','36097','76505156','2016-11-03 15:39:16.000' UNION 
        select '2017-01-17','36132','76505156','2016-11-03 15:52:51.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','41391','76505156','2016-11-10 10:49:30.000'
    )
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY tt.ACCOUNT,a ORDER BY tt.ACCOUNT, rn) AS ROW_IDX FROM (
      SELECT * ,rn-ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, CAST(CREATED_DATE AS DATE),n ORDER BY rn) AS a
      FROM (
          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY CREATED_DATE) AS rn
               ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(CREATED_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY CREATED_DATE),tb.CREATED_DATE)>60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS n
               ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(CREATED_DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY CREATED_DATE),tb.CREATED_DATE),0) AS DiffMin
         FROM tb
    ) AS t
    ) AS tt
    ORDER BY rn
```

```
RptDate    ISSUE_ID ACCOUNT  CREATED_DATE            rn                   n           DiffMin     a                    ROW_IDX
---------- -------- -------- ----------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
2017-01-17 35775    76505156 2016-11-03 12:44:11.000 1                    0           0           0                    1
2017-01-17 35793    76505156 2016-11-03 12:51:43.000 2                    0           7           0                    2
2017-01-17 36097    76505156 2016-11-03 15:39:16.000 3                    1           168         2                    1
2017-01-17 36132    76505156 2016-11-03 15:52:51.000 4                    0           13          1                    1
2017-01-17 41391    76505156 2016-11-10 10:49:30.000 5                    1           9777        4                    1
```

It is another script,Do not use the LAG function, Each step has a statement:

```
    ;WITH tb(RptDate,ISSUE_ID,ACCOUNT,CREATED_DATE )AS(
        select '2017-01-17','35775','76505156','2016-11-03 12:44:11.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 12:51:43.000' UNION
      --  select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 13:47:43.000' UNION
     --   select '2017-01-17','35793','76505156','2016-11-03 14:45:43.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','36097','76505156','2016-11-03 15:39:16.000' UNION 
        select '2017-01-17','36132','76505156','2016-11-03 15:52:51.000' UNION
        select '2017-01-17','41391','76505156','2016-11-10 10:49:30.000'
    ),t1 AS(
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY CREATED_DATE) AS rn FROM tb
    ),t2 AS (
       SELECT t1.*,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,tt.CREATED_DATE,t1.CREATED_DATE)>60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS m 
             ,t1.rn-ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ACCOUNT,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,tt.CREATED_DATE,t1.CREATED_DATE)>60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY t1.CREATED_DATE) AS a
       FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t1 AS tt ON tt.ACCOUNT=t1.ACCOUNT AND tt.rn=t1.rn-1
    ),t3 AS(
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT,t2.a ORDER BY CREATED_DATE) AS ROW_IDX
        FROM t2
    )
    SELECT * FROM t3
    ORDER BY t3.ACCOUNT,t3.CREATED_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I see your have the partition by to the hour of a day, but if for example one account has a date time '2016-11-01 13:47:56.000', another row of the same account has '2016-11-01 14:45:55.000', following your logic, each will count in row_idx as 1, but the gap is within one hour, so the second row should be 2.

Comment: Still wrong. the gap is between this time and min time in the latest group

Comment: Well, I'll think about it, but I kind of doubt if Lead function will work, because it's more like a moving min datetime in one day, not the time gap between sorted continuous rows. Also I am considering over using two while loops...

Comment: @Viviannne the second statement did not use lead, lead also support partition by